# SSRS How to move a row group?

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS 2008 and I created a tablix with several groupings.  However, I see now that my latest grouping is below the details.  This was a mistake because I should have all groupings in my tablix preceding my details group.  All of my groups are adjacent to each other.  How to reposition this group so that it precedes details group instead?

Separate note: is there a way to merge cells for a range of rows?  I only know how to merge cell one row at a time!  And is there a way to copy n rows?  Or do I have to copy one row at a time?

Yes, the row group is actually below the Details group.  See attached images.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Essentially deleting previous post on this. It was based on a bad assumption.]

I would insert a new group where appropriate, then delete cells and columns as appropriate to get the rows for the two groups to match in number: then you can copy and paste the cells (many at once) from the old group to the new.

Make sure that your grouping formulas or fields match and then delete the old group.

(You probably already discovered this, but a clean easy way to create groups is by dragging fields from "Report Data" to the "Row Groups" subwindow: this method will refuse to create a group below details.)

I think the only alternative is to edit the XML and that is dangerous: be careful and keep old versions to revert if needed.

Comment: Yes, the group is really below the details group.  See screenshots.  I know how to get a row above details, but since I have so many rows below details now, this would be alot of work to copy!  Also because I have not found a quick way to copy rows.  Instead, I have to merge/split cells so that they match same size and format.  I can copy and paste multiple rows in BIDS, but I have to select same number of rows and format for destination as source.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, please let me know if u fix this so that I don't have to redo it.

Comment: Yes I think I will just start over since we do not use source control.

Comment: Jamie, if I drag fields into the Row Groups subwindow, it looks like it inserts new row group either as a parent or child group by default.  Is there a way to drag fields there and make them adjacent groups?  Also, if I create groups in this way, how do I specify which group a particular row belongs to?

Comment: I generally avoid adjacent groups: often the same purpose can be accomplished with total rows. (But not always.) Yes, for adjacent groups, you need to right click on the groups in the Row/Column group windows.

Comment: Guess it's just impossible to rearrange / reorder! Something MS forgot to integrate... PS: you're better off choosing 'delete group only'. Otherwise you will break other groups